# Query expression to dot notation

Tags: c#, linq

hei, need some help to convert this linq query to dot notation:

```
            var productions =
            from row in data
            group row by row.PRODUCTION_NAME into gr
            select new
            {
                Group = gr.Key,
                Jobs = from row in gr
                       orderby row.SortFieldCard
                       group row by row.JOB_NAME into job
                       select new { job.Key, Cards = job }
            };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var productions = data
    .GroupBy(row => row.PRODUCTION_NAME)
    .Select(gr => new
    {
        Group = gr.Key,
        Jobs = gr
            .OrderBy(row => row.SortFieldCard)
            .GroupBy(row => row.JOB_NAME)
            .Select(job => new { job.Key, Cards = job })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. If you mean fluent notation of Linq (you said "dot net", and both are dot net (.NET)) I think this should do the trick:

```
var productions = data
  .GroupBy(row => row.PRODUCTION_NAME)
  .Select(gr => new {
    Group = gr.Key,
    Jobs = gr
      .OrderBy(row => row.SortFieldCard)
      .GroupBy(row => row.JOB_NAME)
      .Select(job => new { job.Key, Cards = job})
  });
```